# How would I alter browser cache info (http headers) for scripts and css in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, caching

I would like to have more control over browser caching from solutions, including one that includes scripting libraries and CSS libraries so that I can control how long they reside in the browswer cache.

Libraries like jQuery.js can come from multiple locations (websites, CDNs, etc., but I need to control which versions are being used by my pages and I am operating under an "internal code only" constraint, meaning I can't reference CDNs. I don't know how to specify the cache header with max-age for scripts nor where to do so in SharePoint so that I can control the versioning effectively.

Thanks!